# Why does the Flash always return to the exact time he left when travelling in time?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014, the-flash

A question has been in my mind since I watched *The Flash*. Whenever he travels in time, he returns to the exact same moment he left. Why is it so?

Could he return to any timeline but chooses to return to that timeline which has that specific moment?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I think you are asking about a few to many different aspects of this issue to deal with properly in a single question.  Your first question isn't the same as the relative movement of time (your second) or the disposition of the other timeline (your third).  You should rewrite this to focus on a single question, and ask the other questions separately.  Please read [ask].

Comment: @DavidW I edited it. Only 1 question now

Comment: Much better!  Now that it's a single question, I took the liberty of summarizing the question in the title.  That will attract more attention, and help get better answers.

Comment: For a secong I thought this question was about the Flashpoint Paradox.

Answer (score 1):

he returns to the moment he left because up until he left a version of him exists in the altered timeline it would be a bit awkward having two of yourself running around.

"Could he return to any timeline but chooses to return to that timeline which has that specific moment"

Not entirely certain what your asking the specific moment he left the timeline is only ever going to occur once

Comment: There's also continuity to consider. If he returns a bit ahead of when he left, then he's technically been missing for a period of time. He could miss phone calls, events, tragedies, etc. Flash has learned that the moments he has in the world are precious, and he doesn't want to miss them.